# Windows 8.1 as captive portal

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1, netsh, captive-portal

At my workplace we are creating an embedded solution based on a very compact computer running Win 8.1. The machine will run our server software, will have only lan and wifi access, and must expose a web configuration tool.

I already designed the web app that will run on local IIS, and the server software is ready to go. The only thing I don't really know how to achieve is this:

When the user powers the device he must be able to find it through the available wifi connections (like you direct connect to Chromecasts to configure them). I though of using netsh to create the wifi hotspot, definind a SSID and network key.

The hard part is implementing a sort of "captive portal" feature so that upon connection the customer device (being it a tablet, or smartphone, or whatever) gets the usual "Access to the wifi network" icon, and upon click that must redirect to my webapp initial page.

I know the captive portal theories (http redirect, dns redirect, icmp redirect, etc.) but I can't figure out a concrete way to achieve what I need.

Any help will be extremely appreciated.

Thanks.